# R - List of duplicates with multiple condition

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a Data dataframe like below:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    'id' = sample(1:30, 100, replace=T),
    'first_name' = sample(c("John", "Alex", "Ben"), 100, replace =T),
    'last_name' = sample(c("Bailey", "Smith", "Jones"), 100, replace =T),
    'country' = sample(c("United Kingdom", "United States", "Canada"), 100, replace =T)
)
```

So I know I can use below to get duplicated first_names:

```
Data[duplicated(Data$first_name),]
```

But how can I get a list of duplicated records with **different ID** that have **the same first name and same last night and same country**?

So the desirable results would look like this:

```
country          id          first_name          last_name
United Kingdom   1            John                 Smith
United Kingdom   2            John                 Smith
United States    10           Alex                 Jones
United States    12           Alex                 Jones
```

Comment: please make your code reproducible by using `set.seed`.

Comment: @flodel - Thanks but is the dataframe code above not reproducible?

Comment: @Kash You used `sample`.  So, it is better to have `set.seed()` before creating the dataset.

Comment: assuming you have 3 people sharing the same country/first/last. Would you like to see all three, or just the second and third?

Comment: @flodel - if they all have different IDs, then I want to see all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
Data <- unique(Data)
nm1 <- setdiff(names(Data), "id")
res <- do.call(rbind, 
         lapply(split(Data, as.character(interaction(Data[, nm1]))),function(x) {
                     x[duplicated(x[, nm1]) | duplicated(x[, nm1], fromLast = TRUE), ]
            }))

row.names(res) <- NULL
```

Comment: thanks but I get Error: unexpected ')'  - do you know which it is?

Comment: Can you explain `-1`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative way using `data.table`:

```
ans = unique(setDT(Data))
ans = ans[, list(id=id[.N > 1L]), by = list(first_name, last_name, country)]
setorder(ans, id)
```

First we get just the unique rows over the entire data.table.

Then we group by the columns `first_name`, `last_name` and `country` and keep only those rows where `id` has occurred more than once within that group.

Finally we use the function `setorder` to reorder `ans` by column id.

---

`setorder` reorders the rows of a data.table *by reference*. It's similar to base's order function, but much faster due to a) radix sorting/ordering) and 2) modifies the object in-place (no copies).

For data.table users who are familar with `setkey`, and ask the question why not `setkey`: the result will be identical between the two in this case. But `setkey` sorts *always* in ascending order *and* sets an additional attribute `sorted`. The objective here is just to re-order the rows, not to set the key (requirement for joins). The function `setorder` therefore just makes more sense here.

And `setorder` can also reorder in both ascending and descending order (not relevant here though).

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the "who're" contraction. Even if it exists, you should avoid it for obvious reasons :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
dup <- subset(unique(Data),
              ave(id, country, first_name, last_name, FUN = length) > 1L)
```

where `unique` removes identical persons (same id/country/first/last) and `ave` computes the number of persons sharing country/first/last.

Then you might find it useful to sort your data to put the duplicates next to each other:

```
dup <- dup[with(dup, order(country, first_name, last_name, id)), ]
```

Comment: That's why it is so important to make your example reproducible. I don't think there is anything wrong with my code...

Comment: @Kash, "reliable"? The way to find out if a code produces the desired result is to give the desired result in your question. Again, `set.seed` is necessary when generating data with `sample`.

Comment: And so you know, I find Henrik's and my answer to be the more reliable ones. (My comment about -1 might be a hint.) They're also more readable...

Comment: @flodel Thanks for the comment.  Yes, first I was splitting by `id`, (a mistake), which I changed later.

Comment: @Kash, It seems that the different answers give different results. Can you make your question reproducible and provide desired output?

Comment: @akrun. That's not what I mean. Using `-1` is a bad practice when you have a name for that column: `"id"`. In essence, you are adding an assumption to your code: that `id` will always be the first column of the data. And without checking for that assumption, your code will break or return wrong results when that assumption is not met anymore (imagine the OP loads data from an outside source and the provider decides to insert a column in here.) On a separate note, you cram ten or so functions in a single statement. You should break your code and use good variable names to make it more readable.

Comment: @Kash, the only thing I can imagine that would give different results is if your data contained `NA`. If that's the case, consider filtering these out using `complete.cases`.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` possibility:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(first_name, last_name, country) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  arrange(country, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> data.table(with(Data, table(id, paste(first_name, last_name, country))))[N>0][,.SD[.N>1],by=V1]
                            V1 id N
 1:         Alex Bailey Canada  2 2
 2:         Alex Bailey Canada 26 1
 3: Alex Bailey United Kingdom  7 1
 4: Alex Bailey United Kingdom  8 1
 5: Alex Bailey United Kingdom 16 1
 6: Alex Bailey United Kingdom 29 1
...
```